# Add a Thank you message after SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog() has uploaded the flie

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

```
<a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: &#39;https://xyz/KM/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={B0C944A9F-3E10-46D9-B09C-0D6CC42E2C89}&amp;RootFolder=&#39;, title: &#39;Add a Document&#39; }); return false;" href="#">Upload Documents</a></h4>
```

an Upload Document dialog box appears after this code run then comes a dialog box to enter the properties of the document.
I want a dialog box to appear just after it to show. "Thank you your document has been uploaded"

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek,

You can do this using the dialogReturnValueCallback.
E.g.

```
//Using a generic object.
var options = {
    title: "My Dialog Title",
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    url: "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx",
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult, returnValue)
    {
        alert('Thank you your document has been uploaded');
    }
};

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058.aspx